How do I change the user running DSE?
The user I'm referring to is the user created by the Datastax DSE package install. I'd like to replace that user with another account.
I've found a couple of places where the "Cassandra user" is defined, in the init.d file as well as in the /default/DSE directory.
I've also already reassigned permissions from "Cassandra" to my new user, but the DSE service won't start up unless I run it as root now. I've gone as far as completely wiping out the data, removing the node from the cluster, and repairing it with nodetool, but I can still only run the service as root or change everything back to the "Cassandra" user.
The error message states that it's a read error in the metadata directory, but I've already ensured that the account has rights to it as well as the parent, I've also cleared out the local and peers file that was in the metadata directory.

Could you explain what you're trying to achieve by wanting to replace the default user that comes by default with the package installs & the why behind it? You could also review the securing DSE deployment docs here and here to learn more.

Our security team doesn't like the idea of default users and wants us to make the environment consistent with the rest of our DB products

I was able to do some digging and managed to accomplish switching from the non-default account and verified with Datastax support. I'll use "user1" as an example replacement.
The first step is to create a user and group:

groupadd user1
useradd -d /var/lib/cassandra -g user1 -M -r user1

There are then 3 files to update the user in:

etc/init.d/dse : CASSANDRA_USER="user1"
etc/default/dse : CASSANDRA_USER=user1 CASSANDRA_GROUP=user1
etc/security/limits.d/cassandra.conf : replace "cassandra" with "user1" in all lines

Update directory ownership for all paths in cassandra.yaml, cassandra logs, and anything else that may have been created after the install. You can use something like find // -user cassandra and adjust from there.
If the node was already running, it may cause issues. You can use nodetool removenode oldnodeid to first remove the node, then clear out any data in the data directory. You may also get errors in the metadata directory and will need to remove the 'local' and 'peers' files.
The node can be added afterwards and will sync as long as there is a good seed node in the cluster. You will need to run a nodetool cleanup on all nodes once it comes back up and is joined.

Great yeah, that's the right approach to reach out to DataStax support for the commercial software related questions.

The general proposition with packaged installations is that [mostly] everything is configured for you so unless you know what you're doing, you won't be able to modify the default OS user.
If you prefer to have control over the OS user, we recommend that you instead  install the binary tarball for DataStax Enterprise. Cheers!

Thank you, but using a package install is preferable in this case so that patching and updates can be managed by our satellite server and have a centralized repo for our full stack of products. DS was able to help me research this and we've reached the desired state.
